# How to insert data to MySQL by passing value '' for a auto incremented column?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myproducts` (
              `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
              `type_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NormalPage',
              `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
              PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
              KEY `index_2` (`type_id`,`t`),
              KEY `name` (`name`),
              KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`,`name`(48))
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=189 ;
```

This is my insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`myproducts` (`uid`, `parent_id`, `type_id`, `name`) VALUES ('',20, 'Product Category', 'WaterBottels');
```

Problem Description :
When i use this insert query in my system which is having mysql version 5.5.16 it is perfectly inserting the record but when i try this in another system which is also having mysql version 5.5.16 it is giving problem.

I do know we should pass NULL or '0' for the auto increment column , but my question why it is working for my instance.

As it is working for my instance , i am considering we can pass '' as the value for auto increment column. if so to work it out in other system do i need to change any mysql configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this query to insert:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`myproducts` (`parent_id`, `type_id`, `name`) 
VALUES (20, 'Product Category', 'WaterBottels');
```

You don't need to specify the primary key column as that will be auto inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Since You are using `uid` as a `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

MySQL uses the `AUTO_INCREMENT` keyword to perform an auto-increment feature.

By default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

You can use

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`myproducts` (`parent_id`, `type_id`, `name`) VALUES (20, 'Product Category', 'WaterBottels');
```

instead of

```
  INSERT INTO `mydb`.`myproducts` (`uid`, `parent_id`, `type_id`, `name`) VALUES ('',20, 'Product Category', 'WaterBottels');
```

Answer (score 0):

Values is not required for AUTO_INCREMENT fields as it will be auto generated. so you can insert a row without specifying the value for column uid.

Answer (score 0):

user either of the following

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`myproducts` (`uid`, `parent_id`, `type_id`, `name`) VALUES
 (null,20, 'Product Category', 'WaterBottels');
```

OR

```
  INSERT INTO `mydb`.`myproducts` ( `parent_id`, `type_id`, `name`) VALUES
     (20, 'Product Category', 'WaterBottels');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your column **uid** id auto incremented, you don't need to pass a value while insertion. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`myproducts` (`parent_id`, `type_id`, `name`) VALUES (20, 'Product Category', 'WaterBottels');
```

This will work on all systems and your **uid** will get auto incremented.